# Is it possible to use Furl.Http with the OWIN TestServer?

Tags: owin, dotnet-httpclient, flurl

I'm using the OWIN TestServer which provides me an HttpClient to do my in memory calls to the test server. I'm wondering if there's a way of passing in the existing HttpClient for Flurl to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPDATE:*** Much of the information below is no longer relevant in Flurl.Http 2.x. Specifically, most of Flurl's functionality is contained in the new `FlurlClient` object (which wraps `HttpClient`) and not in a custom message handler, so you're not losing functionality if you provide a different `HttpClient`. Further, as of Flurl.Http 2.3.1, you no longer need a custom factory to do this. It's as easy as:

```
var flurlClient = new FlurlClient(httpClient);
```

---

Flurl provides an `IHttpClientFactory` interface that allows you to customize `HttpClient` construction. However, much of Flurl's functionality is provided by a custom `HttpMessageHandler`, which is added to `HttpClient` on construction. You wouldn't want to hot-swap it out for an already instantiated `HttpClient` or you'll risk breaking Flurl.

Fortunately, OWIN TestServer is also driven by an `HttpMessageHandler`, and you can pipeline multiple when you create an `HttpClient`.

Start with a custom factory that allows you to pass in the `TestServer` instance:

```
using Flurl.Http.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Owin.Testing;

public class OwinTestHttpClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly TestServer _testServer;

    public OwinTestHttpClientFactory(TestServer server) {
        _testServer = server;
    }

    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler() {
        // TestServer's HttpMessageHandler will be added to the end of the pipeline
        return _testServer.Handler;
    }
}
```

Factories can be registered globally, but since you need a different `TestServer` instance for each test, I'd recommend setting it on the `FlurlClient` instance, which is a [new capability](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/wiki/Release-Notes) as of Flurl.Http 0.7. So your tests would look something like this:

```
using (var testServer = TestServer.Create(...)) {
    using (var flurlClient = new FlurlClient()) {
        flurlClient.Settings.HttpClientFactory = new OwinTestHttpClientFactory(testServer);

        // do your tests with the FlurlClient instance. 2 ways to do that:
        url.WithClient(flurlClient).PostJsonAsync(...);
        flurlClient.WithUrl(url).PostJsonAsync(...);
    }
}
```