# Can I use FlurlClient with Asp.Net Core TestServer?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, integration-testing, flurl

We are using FlurlClient in a few projects and familiar with their fluent interface.
We now want to use it in asp.net core integration tests using TestServer.
The example from 
http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2017/09/27/testing-aspnetcore.html

```
_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
                             .UseStartup<Startup>());
_client = _server.CreateClient();
```

I was going to change code to

```
_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
                             .UseStartup<Startup>());
var httpClient = _server.CreateClient();
_client = new FlurlClient(httpClient);
```

and use all FlurlClient methods/extensions.

But then I noticed 
[Is it possible to use Furl.Http with the OWIN TestServer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090498/is-it-possible-to-use-furl-http-with-the-owin-testserver/33128757#33128757) which described that more work is required in owin implementation.

Is approach for Asp.Net Core TestServer similar? Or is it simplified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's *much* simplified, and your proposed change is exactly right. The question you linked to is old and my answer contains information that's no longer relevant in 2.x. (I have updated it.) In fact, the ability to provide an existing `HttpClient` directly in a `FlurlClient` constructor was added [very recently](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/298), and with this specific use case in mind.

Here's an extension method I use as a replacement for `CreateClient`; you might find it handy if you do this a lot:

```
public static class TestServerExtensions
{
    public static IFlurlClient CreateFlurlClient(this TestServer server) => 
        new FlurlClient(server.CreateClient());
}
```

Comment: Hi @todd-menier One Question: In my specific scenario I need to add a HttpClientHandler to testservers CreateClient-Method to be able to make calls via SSL with a self-signed certificate in an integration test (using testcontainers and having a keycloak spin up in docker and want to get validate a token when calling my apps API, this fails atm because the cert is not valid). As far as I found out, it is not possible with Testserver itself. So would it be possible when I wrap the HttpClient into a FlurlClient?

Comment: @Dominik No, if it can't be done with TestServer/HttpClient, then wrapping it with Flurl won't help. Flurl just puts a prettier face on HttpClient but still defers the bulk of the actual work to it.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I thought so. So i added this question and hoping for better luck there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062832/calling-thirdparty-container-with-net-core-testhost-testserver-via-ssl-bypass :)

Answer (score 0):

For Flurl 4.x the solution looks a bit differently due to API changes if you don't want to use an explicit `FlurlClient`, but rather the clientless approach. Assuming you have a `WebApplicationFactory`:

```cs
var webApplicationFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>()
     .WithWebHostBuilder(
         builder =>
         {
             // Your configuration 
         });
```

You need to copy at least the base address to the Flurl and add a custom middleware that "redirects" the HTTP calls to the test server:

```cs
 FlurlHttp
     .ConfigureClientForUrl(string.Empty) // Omit or change if you're using different URIs in your tests
     .ConfigureHttpClient(client => client.BaseAddress = webApplicationFactory.ClientOptions.BaseAddress)
     .AddMiddleware(() => new TestServerMessageHandler(webApplicationFactory.Server));
```

Where `TestServerMessageHandler` is:

```
private class TestServerMessageHandler(Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer testServer) : DelegatingHandler
 { 
     protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         InnerHandler?.Dispose();
         InnerHandler = testServer.CreateHandler();
         return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
     }
 }
```

`InnerHandler` is the Flurl handler, since we want to use a handler from our test server, we need to dispose and replace it.

This enables you to make calls like `"/v0/test".GetJsonAsync<SomeDto>()` in your tests, that Flurl will execute with the test server.